# What are the proper rules for printf conversions?

Tags: c, printf

I have this function call for printf:

```
printf("%-+05.6d", 133);
```

With this output:

```
+000133
```

I'm having trouble with the rules of how the printf flags interact with each other since it seems they are given conflicting rules.

According to the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)(man 3 printf):

```
0

The value should be zero padded. For d, i, o, u, x, X, a, A, e, E, f, F, g, and G conversions, the converted value is padded on the left with zeros rather than blanks. If the 0 and - flags both appear, the 0 flag is ignored. If a precision is given with a numeric conversion (d, i, o, u, x, and X), the 0 flag is ignored. For other conversions, the behavior is undefined.
```

So according to this, the 0 flag should be ignored since there is both a '-' flag and a precision specified, yet it is still printing 0's.

According to the man for diouxX conversions:

```
The precision, if any, gives the minimum number of digits that must appear; if the converted value requires fewer digits, it is padded on the left with zeros.
```

So with both of these rules, it would seem that specific diouxX conversion rule applies here since 0's are still being printed, but then why does the man say the 0's get ignored?

Since precision is applied here, shouldn't the '0' flag be ignored and padded with spaces instead?

Answer (score 3):

You have a mess. The `0` is ignored, try it:

```
printf("%-+5.6d", 133);
```

Output

```
+000133
```

The problem you have is there are multiple overriding flags specified. You correct cite that a `-` (left justified) overrides the `0`. The sign flag `+` provides a space for either `+/-` before the string on all occasions.

The next conflict is `5.6`. You specify a *field-width* modifier of `5`, but then specify the *precision* as `6`. For `d, i, o, u, x, and X` conversions the *precision* specifies the number of **digits that will appear**. (see [C11 Standard -7.21.6.1 The fprintf function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1)) So while not specifically stated, the *precision* being greater than the *field-width* effectively overrides the field width resulting in `6-digits` in addition to the `+` sign being printed for `133`.

So the crux of the issue is **"Why if `-` overrides the `0` flag are `0s` still printed?"** Here there are some technical hairs to be split. Since you have specified `-` (left justified) and both a *field-width* and *precision*, the `0` is ignored but you have stated that 6-digits shall be printed and the result will be left-justified. So you get `0s` based on the `precision` and then total number of digits is left-justified with explicit `+/-` being provided for the sign.

Remove the precision and you will see the effect of `-` overriding `0`:

```
printf("%-+05.d", 133);
```

Output:

```
+133
```

(there is an empty  following the final `3` to make a total field-width of `5`)

(**note:** -- can you rely on this being completely portable? -- probably not, there is likely a bit of implementation defined leeway left in the standard for flag sequence interpretation that may result in a slightly different ordering of flags with some compilers)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation that you quote, the `0` in the format is ignored, meaning it has no effect on whether there are zeros in the output. Then, you provide a precision of `.6` with an integer format, which means the result must show 6 or more digits. The zeros you see are needed to fill up that minimum number of digits.

If the format did not include `-` or `.6`, the `05` would mean that the entire number would take up at least than 5 characters, padded by zeros, so the output would be `+0133`.